# Getting HTML tags after the XML Parsing?

Tags: iphone

I'm getting HTML tags in response and I want to display the response data in **TextView**. 
Like:-(this is my data after the parsing)
like share, in 2010&#39;s ninth quarter.
international workers.
How can i show this data directly is there a way to remove these HTML tags after the parsing.
I also used this

```
[temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&acute;" withString:@"'" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[temp length])];
```

this works after parsing the data before displays to the **TextView**.
But what about other tags and special characters.
Can any one provide me the better way to do this work...

Thanks in advance.